# How do I limit the file matching of the xcopy exclusion list

Tags: file, xcopy

I am running into an issue where xcopy matches file names that I didn't expect it to match...  Some file names have patterns in them that match a file extension that I'm trying to exclude.  Unfortunately xcopy simply matches patterns...

My exclusion file is configured to exclude `.xml` files, but the source directory contains two project outputs (`Acme.XML.dll` and `Acme.XML.Providers.dll`), which get caught by the filter and excluded.

The copy script that we use is a common script for all projects we work with, so I really don't want to do a "one-off" modification, just for these two projects.  I would also like to stay with a solution that involves a file list of exclusions.  This script is configured in the build events of 30+ VS.NET projects, so updating a file when requirements change, is much easier that modifying all the projects...

#### XCOPY Command:

```
 xcopy "C:\MNT\Dev\SRC\Acme\TestProject\bin\Release\*.*" "C:\MNT\Dev\Acme\ClassLibraries\AnyCPU\Release" /I /Y /EXCLUDE:C:\MNT\Dev\BuildExclusionList_Release.txt
```

#### Contents of BuildExclusionList_Release.txt

```
.tmp
DAL_GENERATED_FLAG.TXT
.xml
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to answer this question after several hours of digging around the web.  As it turns out, simply appending a backslash `\` to the item in the exclusion list will limit its matching to the end of a file name, in addition to a path name.

I had assumed that slashes only applied to folders, but xcopy applies them to file names as well.  Using `.xml\`, allowed me to exclude `Acme.XML.xml` (The XML documentation), but not `Acme.XML.dll` (The project output)

#### Updated BuildExclusionList_Release.txt

```
.tmp\
DAL_GENERATED_FLAG.TXT
.xml\
```

#### Project Build Output

```
Acme.XML -> C:\MNT\Dev\SRC\Acme\XML\bin\Release\Acme.XML.dll
xcopy "C:\MNT\Dev\SRC\Acme\XML\bin\Release\*.*" "C:\MNT\Dev\Acme\ClassLibraries\AnyCPU\Release" /I /Y /EXCLUDE:C:\MNT\Dev\Acme\BuildExclusionList_Release.txt
C:\MNT\Dev\SRC\Acme\XML\bin\Release\Acme.Common.dll
C:\MNT\Dev\SRC\Acme\XML\bin\Release\Acme.Logging.dll
C:\MNT\Dev\SRC\Acme\XML\bin\Release\Acme.XML.dll
C:\MNT\Dev\SRC\Acme\XML\bin\Release\Acme.Math.dll
4 File(s) copied
========== Rebuild All: 1 succeeded, 0 failed, 0 skipped ==========
```